# Do roasted peanuts in their shells require a hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food

I know that non-Israel grown raw peanuts in their shell are considered plain "vegetables" / legumes and do not require kosher certification, as other untouched fresh fruit / veggies.

Shelled peanuts roasted in oil do require certification, as these go through some manufacturing processes where eitherthe oil itself may not be kosher or something unkosher may be in the processing plant that came in contact with the peanuts.

What about the roasting process if the peanuts are still in the shell? I heard that no oil is used in this process - they are heat roasted. I don't know if most places use a dedicated oven that just roasts peanuts. Furthemore, I had heard that since the shell is not eaten and nothing penetrates the shell, anyway, there wouldn't be a concern even if it came into contact with something non-kosher.

Can anyone verify this claim regarding unshelled roasted peanuts?

Comment: Considering that the shell often cracks and is porous, I doubt the assertion that "nothing penetrates the shell" is a factual one...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I had thought of that, myself. However, there may be something regarding the roasting process itself where this wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Roasted nuts of any variety are permissible without a hecsher per Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi.

> Questioner
>
> A. Are roasted pistachio nuts, or roasted nuts in general,
> with salt okay without a hechsher?
>
> B. How about a trail mix made with assorted nuts, raisins, peanut oil
> and salt.
>
> Thanks.
>
> Reply of Yitzchak Abadi:
>
> A. Yes
>
> B. Yes

Source: http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=5922&highlight=

i would suggest that you search his website as you will find many more halachot and answers to questions that would be very valuable to your everyday life. In general, Kashrut agencies have something to gain by stating things need hecshers. So it might not always be the best policy to trust what they have to say regarding such issues in which they have a very real reason to be biased.

Comment: Re your last sentence - Is the site you listed a kashrut agency, itself? What makes them unbiased?

Comment: The site listed is the website run by Yitzchak Abadi a world renowned posek. He is very knowledgeable about halacha and food industrial practices. He started the website to help people sort out kashrut questions, pointing out that sages of old never ate in kosher restaurants, and how many countries in the world don't have hecshers and the Jews there are doing just fine.

Comment: @Aaron Those sages and Jews also didn't have vaccines, etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA i just now saw your comment. The sages of old also didn't know we have worms in fish flesh that are parasites, they enter in from being eaten, and therefore are  not kosher, but the OU and other "orthodox" kashrut agencies follow the rulings of old. But they only follow rulings of old when it suits them, and follow "new findings" and research also when it suits them.

Comment: @DoubleAA https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/is-this-worm-kosher-the-kashrus-of-tolayim-in-fish/

Comment: @Aaron Modern manufacturing being complicated and using lots of different ingredients/techniques is not a new finding. It's just Metziut. Pretending that modern food manufacture techniques are as easy to verify the Kashrut of as ancient ones is just stupid. You can argue its still sufficiently verifiable, but it's definitely not just as easily verifiable. So the argument you presented doesn't follow.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's very complicated indeed. And that's why one needs a competant Rav that doesn't gain or lose anything on these processies. If a judge accidentally ran into someone that later up showed up to be judged by him and his beit din, he would have to recuse himself, because of inherent conflict of interest. Yet somehow Kashrut agencies don't have to worry about this?

Comment: @Aaron You're changing the point. Your first comment's argument is stupid. So I called you out on it. I'm not going to debate the actual issue here in the comments.

Comment: @DoubleAA i'm not trying to say that Kashrut agencies are evil or bad, but it seems to me the system is inherently flawed when they are deciding p'sak on their own. If they existed and only followed the rulings of great Rabbanim that were not a part of their organizations, then i think it would be better for everyone.

Comment: @Aaron Perhaps, but that's no excuse for you to present a stupid argument.

Comment: @DoubleAA i'm not changing the points. Things are complicated now, but some things are not so. Food flavorings are designed by processies you and i don't understand. But in terms of kashrut, is the flavoring a food or not? If it's not a food, then its rules are simple! Is corn syrup kitniyot or is it sufficiently changed? There are some key rules that if applied across the board make things a lot simpler. And the job of a good rav is to teach you those concepts.

Comment: @Aaron No the job of a good rav is to paskin the opinions and teach you the opinions he paskins for you like, not just to make things easy for you. The most Meikil position is not always the way to Paskin. And yes you changed from complicated foods, to rabbis having bad incentives, back to complicated foods.

Comment: @DoubleAA i don't think Rav Abadi makes things easy. He makes things straightforward and simple. Like Maran attempted to do, or the Rambam. Although when both of their big works were published there was much hoopla then as well

Comment: @Aaron (I note none of Rs Abadi, Karo, or Maimon would carry in any modern Eruv...) It's just as simple conceptually to say flavoring is food as to say it isn't. In fact it seems no different than any classical spice. How is R Abadi's position on that issue more simple? Unless by simple you mean Meikil/easy.

Answer (score 0):

See the CRC statement on peanuts which omits dry roasted peanuts from its list of peanuts requiring certification.

http://www.crcweb.org/fruit%20&%20veg%20guide.php which states

Peanuts- A general inspection is needed to rule out obvious infestation. All canned, jarred or cooked, boiled or oil roasted nuts require a reliable hashgacha.

See also this link that confirms this
https://books.google.com/books?id=l0GXha1h3eIC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=dry+roasted+peanuts+hashgacha&source=bl&ots=ydT7Sx_0QS&sig=ADBhMU_B_DWncaAiRLB7ZnC-5pk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW7vy6wpnLAhUhmYMKHTdcBx84HhDoAQgoMAI#v=onepage&q=dry%20roasted%20peanuts%20hashgacha&f=false

Comment: I'm not sure your conclusion is correct. The article has a separate listing for "nuts" amd "peanuts", and under "nuts", they state that dry roasted nuts DO require certification. Scientifically, peanuts are in their own category and are considered legumes, not nuts. However, since we commonly call them "nuts", it's unclear if when CRC says "nuts" it includes peanuts in that category. I assume that since they did make a separate listing for peanuts, the answer is that they are not included, but, I'll see if I can contact them to verify.

Comment: Additionally, "cooked" in this context clearly seems to mean "roasted," since boiling and oil roasted are already covered (bishul and tigun vs. tzli). Is there a fourth way to "cook" peanuts that doesn't involve boiling or roasting in oil?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Most nuts can be "dry roasted". I've done this with almonds and pecans. You put them in the oven with no oil and heat them for a while. I've never done this with peanuts, and I think trying to roast them while still in the shell is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

In the southern states (of the USA), sometimes peanuts are roasted with some pork products to give them a certain taste (e.g., http://www.sarcasticcooking.com/2012/09/06/bacon-sage-roasted-peanuts/). I have seen packaged roasted peants sold at roadside stands with no indication of their contents.  In short, there is a risk in just looking at the product or the ingredients.  Anything cooked is a potential kashrut problem.

Comment: "I have seen packaged roasted peants [sic] sold at roadside stands with no indication of their contents. In short, there is a risk in just looking at the product or the ingredients. Anything cooked is a potential kashrut problem." What? That doesn't follow. The fact that some items don't list their ingredients does not indicate that there is risk by checking the lists on those that do.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not all ingredients have to be listed, only those above a certain percentage, as I understand it. Checking ingredients is a very incomplete approach to keeping kosher, but much better than nothing.

Comment: Whatever your reasoning is, you should include it in the post and not make arguments that don't follow. If that is your reason you should probably make sure you know what the laws actually are about ingredient listing and  how law of Bittul can play into that. If you don't know what you're talking about, better not to say anything at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA  I do not understand the reason for your strongly worded critique of what I wrote in my comments and the logic of your critique of my answer. But you have many more points than I on this SE, so perhaps you could explain these to me.

Comment: @Yehuda W Please provide a source for this notion that ingredients don't have to be listed.  As far as I know, this is an outright falsehood.

Comment: @Aaron  
This website http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;sid=8a700930f3cb597eb25581cb9e6556af;rgn=div5;view=text;node=21%3A2.0.1.1.2;idno=21;cc=ecfr#se21.2.101_122
contains this statement concerning exemption from the labeling requirement:
"(b) Substances that are added to a food during processing, are converted into constituents normally present in the food, and do not significantly increase the amount of the constitutents naturally found in the food."

Comment: @Aaron  
Also, look at this publication http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=1&SID=4bf49f997b04dcacdfbd637db9aa5839&ty=HTML&h=L&mc=true&n=pt21.2.101&r=PART#se21.2.101_19 and search for terms "low volume" and "small business" both of which have exemptions from some labeling.

Comment: @YehudaW Goodjob. You have discovered that food processing aids don't have to be labeled. Unfortunately, these occur in such small amounts they are usually nullified. But even more importantly, they aren't ingredients, they are things like: activated charcoal, which filters out impurities [in the food]. Something added to the food, but gets converted into a substance already present in the food. This could be something like a pH adjuster that converts to salt and doesn’t significantly add to the level of salt in the food. Etc. etc.

Comment: @YehudaW And the low volume exception means they have exception from labeling, not that they get to just ignore labeling certain ingredients.  Typically they will have NO label. So if you are on the side of the road and there is a guy selling fried popcorn with no ingredients label, don't buy it. If you're in a market, and there are labels you can read, then you can rely on them. It's that simple. Yes, you can worry that "food processing aids" don't have to be labeled, but they don't have any bearing on the kashrut of your food. If you want to be paranoid for paranoids sake, i won't stop you